# Second separate network using single ISP-provided address

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I have a standard home network consisting of internet access provided by my cable company which is then disseminated to a variety of wired and wireless devices via a router.

I would like to create a second wireless network that is separate from my current one. This new wireless network would have extra access controls including access restrictions to some web sites using both IP address restrictions and using the OpenDNS DNS servers.

The picture below illustrates the current configuration. The question is: how can I connect `ROUTER B` to the internet using my current equipment (without buying another IP address from the cable company)?

```
          W
MODEM --> ROUTER A --> ANTENNA <------> COMP 3
           1 2 3 4 
           | |   
           | |   
COMP 1 <---' |           W
             |   ?? <--> ROUTER B --> ANTENNA <---> COMP 4
COMP 2 <-----'            1 2 3 4 

W = WAN port
```

So, in the above picture, `COMP 4` is connected via wireless to this second network and cannot access anything on the first network and uses different different DNS servers.

In case it matters, `ROUTER A` is a Linksys WRT54GL while `ROUTER B` is a D-Link DI-624.

Answer (score 1):

Connect the WAN port of router B to a switch port on router A.  That will make the wireless network on router B a separate network from the one on Router A.

Be sure to set a different IP address range on router's A and B.  For example if the local network on router A is 192.168.0.0/24 make the network on router B on 192.168.1.0/24.

```
          W
MODEM --> ROUTER A --> ANTENNA <------> COMP 3
           1 2 3 4 
           | | |  
           | | '---------  
COMP 1 <---' |           W
             |           ROUTER B --> ANTENNA <---> COMP 4
COMP 2 <-----'            1 2 3 4 

W = WAN port
```